# Куда сохраняются файлы Preferences в виджетах Android

Tags: android, android-preferences

Доброго дня !) Создал Android виджет, в нем сохраняю данные в Preferences. Зашел в проводнике в Android>Data однако пакета своего виджета не нахожу. Почему так ?Возможно они сохраняются в другое место ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы, судя по всему, смотрите не там. Данные приложения сохраняются не на SD-карте, а в корне файловой системы. Почему я думаю, что вы смотрите на SD-карте? Потому, что путь начинается с `Android`, а в памяти телефона - просто с `data`. Смотреть нужно в `data/data/<пакет вашего приложения>`

Comment: Дело в том что у меня в аппарате нету sd карты. И что еще примечательно, пакеты других приложений там есть. Телефон meizu m2 note

Comment: @Accami, SD карта может быть виртуальной. Она называется еще "встроенная память". Пакеты там есть только тех приложений, которые захотели туда записать данные. Как я и сказал, ищите ваши данные тут: `data/data/<пакет вашего приложения>`. Для этог овам необходим root доступ.

Comment: Да, вы правы, в Root Explorer нашел свой пакет, спасибо !)